# Comment pourrait-on traduire « crunch time » ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

En anglais, « *crunch time* » désigne une période décisive pendant laquelle on est sous pression et où il faut fournir beaucoup d'efforts d'un seul coup. Par exemple, à la fin d'un gros projet où il faut tout boucler avant une date butoire qui arrive à grand pas. Ou bien avant des examens, quand il faut tout réviser rapidement.

Les traductions que j'ai trouvé (WordReference, Reverso) proposent « moment critique », « moment décisif ». Mais pour moi ça ne rend pas bien l'idée qu'il faut faire beaucoup d'efforts sur une courte période. Un moment peut être critique/décisif mais se jouer sur un coup de chance, par exemple.

Comment: J'ai une petite suggestion d'idée : "le moment de mettre un bon coup de collier".

Comment: En restauration, on parle de "coup de feu".

Answer (score 3):

En [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/comment-pourrait-on-traduire-crunch-time#comment60694_29905) on a référé au [*coup*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coup/19796/locution?q=coup#168437), et je suis familier (au Québec) avec des tours comme *c'est l'heure de donner un bon/dernier coup*. D'autre part on a aussi au figuré le [*dernier droit*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=dernier%20droit&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=4442) (plus régulièrement la *dernière ligne droite*) « pour désigner la dernière étape ou les derniers moments qui précèdent un événement quelconque », provenant de l'univers des courses de chevaux et de l'athlétisme (BDL). Ainsi que le *dernier sprint* ou *sprint final*. Enfin au Québec on a parfois le [*rush*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=sprint&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=4408) (de fin de session par exemple) ; ça donne probablement *c'est le temps de rusher*. Tous référant à l'idée de fournir des efforts au moment opportun, un peu comme le [*crunch time*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crunch_time), avant la fin.

Comment: On utilise aussi `rush` en France, dans le monde de l'entreprise du moins ;)

Comment: Je mets un +1 car malgré le manque de formattage, cette réponse me paraît la plus complète. J'ajouterais le (dernier) coup de collier

Answer (score 1):

Une expression qui nous vient (je crois) des publicitaires et que j'entends depuis une trentaine d'années est : *être en charrette*.

> Nous sommes actuellement en charrette pour boucler une réponse à un appel d'offre

Comment: il me semble que c'est `être charrette` (sans le "en"), mais je me trompe peut être

Answer (score 1):

Le terme qui vient à l'esprit est *le rush* :

> C'est le rush pour finir le projet
>
> C'est le gros rush pour réviser avant l'examen

Comme *crunch time* en anglais, "le rush" signifie la situation d'être sous pression, plutôt que l'effort qui en résulte. Ce n'est pas le cas de *rush* en anglais, qui désigne l'action elle-même (il me semble qu'au Québec on dit rusher avec le même sens qu'en anglais).

En tout cas l'emploi de *crunch* en France laissera tes interlocuteurs surtout penser aux barres de chocolat au riz soufflé de cette marque.